# Where do you want feedback about the "datacenter redudancy test", if any?

Tags: support

I saw the [blog post](http://blog.serverfault.com/2012/10/11/working-towards-failure-testing-this-weekend/) earlier, and today the banner that also links to the post:

> We will be testing our redundant datacenter at 16:00 UTC - hopefully you won't notice (except for this message)

Right at the start I *thought I* saw some unexpected behavior with my rep on the site, *but apparently my brain isn't able to grasp UTC :D*.

*When it starts*, is there any place where (and when) the SO team would like to receive feedback, if any at all?

Comment: 16:00 UTC hasn't come yet, it's 45 minutes in the future at time of posting this comment. That being said, if you have a specific problem/bug on SO, just report it here.

Comment: D'oh, damn time zones making me feel stupid :D - updated my question, thx for the response.

Comment: Well, I can't speak for the SE staff, but problems during/after these types of things are usually discussed here on Meta when they happen - often with a bunch of rapid-fire duplicate bug reports with varying levels of annoyance/desperation/outrage at SO being down ;)

Comment: The blog post actually says 3PM UTC, we're already half an hour past that and everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: ...and after the short break, everything's back to working normally.

Answer (score 1):

Meta Stack Overflow is where you should report any persistent issues you experience with Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange in general. Make sure to tag your questions [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [support](/questions/tagged/support), and give as much information for the problem as possible.

In case the unthinkable happens and the sites go down (for more than a few minutes), check out [#stackoverflow](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23stackoverflow&src=hash) and [#stackexchange](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23stackexchange&src=hash) on Twitter for updates.

Comment: Was just about to write that, we will keep an eye on #stackoverflow . We will probably aware of any issues, the most helpful thing might be odd things that don't seem to be working right once we are up an running from our secondary DC in Oregon.